# Yii2:link to related update page from different model

Tags: php, yii2

I have two models namely `daily_ward_entry` and `discharge_note` both the models are related by `discharge_note.regn_number` = `daily_ward_entry.ipd_patient_id`. I want to create a link from `daily_ward_entry` to update page on `discharge_note`.

I can't make out how to create such link.

I have tried like this, but it doesn't redirect at all.

```
<?= Html::a('Go to Discharge NOte', 
['discharge-note/update', $dischargenote->regn_number =>$model->ipd_patient_id], 
['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is not correct send parameter. parameter send with key-value pairs. see [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html#creating-urls)

```
<?= Html::a('Go to Discharge NOte', 
['discharge-note/update', 'id' => $model->ipd_patient_id], 
['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Comment: Hi Vitalik - Still I am getting the error for `missing parameter id`. the URL generated with your suggestion is like `index.php?r=discharge-note%2Fupdate&regn_number=1`

Comment: i edit code. i change `regn_number` to `id`. but i not sure  if it helps. because i don't know your rule in urlmanager